# Echoed radio buttons won't check

Tags: php, wordpress, forms, radio-button

Forgive my php, I'm very new to it.

I've created a category loop in Wordpress to output different markup based on the category (so category 1's element will get a unique class, etc). I have it so it's echoing radio buttons that the user can select from. Everything works fine except the radio buttons don't check. I can uncheck them, but I can't check them. The static html version works fine.

Static (working) version:

```
<input id="type-1" name="s1" type="radio" class="type-1">
<label for="type-1" class="label-1">&nbsp;2010 </label>

<input id="type-3" name="s1" type="radio" class="type-3">
<label for="type-3" class="label-3">&nbsp;2011 <span>.</span> </label>

<input id="type-4" name="s1" type="radio" class="type-4">
<label for="type-4" class="label-4">&nbsp;2012 <span>.</span> </label>

<input id="type-5" name="s1" type="radio" class="type-5">
<label for="type-5" class="label-5">&nbsp;2013 <span>.</span> </label>
```

Dynamic (not working) version:

```
    <?php
    $cat_args=array(
      'orderby' => 'name',
      'order' => 'ASC'
       );
    $categories=get_categories($cat_args);
      foreach($categories as $category) { 
        $args=array(
          'category__in' => array($category->term_id),
          'caller_get_posts'=>1
        );
        $posts=get_posts($args);
          if ($posts) {
            echo "<input id=\"type-{$category->term_id}\" name=\"s1\" type=\"radio\" class=\"type-{$category->term_id}\"><label for=\"type-{$category->term_id}\" class=\"label-{$category->term_id}\">&nbsp;{$category->name}<span>.</span> </label>";
            foreach($posts as $post) {
              setup_postdata($post); ?>
              <?php
            } // foreach($posts
          } // if ($posts
        } // foreach($categories
    ?>
```

UPDATE: Figured it out. I'm an idiot and it had nothing to do with the above code. It was a silly CSS problem.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing curly braces in your output, you should be writing it like this:

```
echo "<input id=\"type-{$category->term_id}\" ......";
```

Check this link for details:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing

Alternatively, you can use string concatenation:

```
echo "<input id=\"type-" . $category->term_id . "\" ......";
```

Or you could use `sprintf()`, which I personally like (http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php)

Comment: Thanks for you help. I had used concatenation originally but with the same results. I've added the curly braces but no difference. It's strange, because when looking at the outputted HTML the final code is identical to the static version. Only the buttons won't check.